# how to handle inApp subscription type when it purchesed but not download yet

Tags: iphone, subscription, storekit

my InApp type is subscription.

once i tap on OK it always call

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

how to handle it call on  completeTransaction ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will finish transaction solve this?

ie:

```
[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
```